# Show only a few users and hide others

Tags: javascript, html, css, mongodb, meteor

Can anyone explain how to make a user list like as shown in the image below...
[image: User list]

I'm making a project in Meteor and using Materialize for template and I want to display the list of assigned users. If there are more than a particular count(say 5) of users i want them to be displayed like on that image... I have tried googling this and haven't found anything useful. I also checked the Materialize website and found nothing useful. So if anyone has an idea please help share it.

Ok so this is the output html, in this case i only have one member but in real case I will have more:

```
<div class="row"> ==$0
<label class="active members_padding_card_view">Members</label>
<div class="toolBarUsers flex" style="float:right;">
<dic class="other-profile" style="background-color:#f06292;">
<span>B</span>
</div>
```

This is the .js code

```
Template.profile.helpers({
randomInitials: function () {
var chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var nLetter = chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*chars.length));
var sLetter = chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*chars.length));
return nLetter + sLetter;
},
tagColor: function () {
var colors = ["#e57373","#f06292","#ba68c8","#9575cd","#7986cb","#64b5f6","#4fc3f7","#4dd0e1","#4db6ac","#81c784","#aed581","#dce775","#fff176","#ffd54f","#ffb74d","#ff8a65","#a1887f","#e0e0e0","#90a4ae"];
return colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
},
randomAllowed : function(possible) {
    var count = Math.floor((Math.random() * possible) + 1);
    if(count == 1) {
        return;
    }
    return "none";
},

membersList() {
    const instance = Template.instance();
    const cardDataId = new Mongo.ObjectID(instance.data.cardData._id.valueOf());
    return CardDataMembers.find({lkp_card_data_fkeyi_ref: cardDataId});
},
memberData: function() {
    // We use this helper inside the {{#each posts}} loop, so the context
    // will be a post object. Thus, we can use this.xxxx from above memberList
    return Meteor.users.findOne(this.lkp_user_fkeyi_ref);
},
showMembers() {
    const instance = Template.instance();
    const cardDataId = new Mongo.ObjectID(instance.data.cardData._id.valueOf());

    let membersCount = CardDataMembers.find({lkp_card_data_fkeyi_ref: cardDataId}).count();
    ////console.log(membersCount);
    if (membersCount > 0) {
        $('.modal-trigger').leanModal(); 
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
},
});
```

Right now if I add a lot of users I get this:
[image: This...]

Comment: I can't see any component in that framework that similar to this. If I'm wrong, please post a link to the component. If so, you have to write it yourself. It's not that problem. Using css and a few lines of javascript.

Comment: I would like an example of code CSS and Javascript to see how to write this please...

Comment: Ok will try... I'll post the code

Comment: Let me know when you finish by [notify me](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: @MoshFeu posted the code...

Comment: Can you please add the output html? (not a server code like `{{#if showMembers}}`)

Comment: @MoshFeu you mean this??

Comment: Almost.. Add the whole html (I mean, it should contains at least 8 `div`s for each user isn't?

Comment: @MoshFeu yes if I add more users it shows them but i dont want to show 8 users... i want it to be five users and the 6th circle would show +3

Comment: Also why does this question have -1 vote score? I provided the code, please remove the negative score

Comment: Please create a workable [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) which produce the screenshot you added? For the downvoting: you can see why people think that this question need to be closed. That's will give you an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after quite some time I have solved the problem. I am posting my answer here for anyone that will in the future experience a similar issue...
Have a good day!

I have added the following lines of code to my template:

```
return CardDataMembers.find({lkp_card_data_fkeyi_ref: cardDataId},{sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 3});

diffMembers(){
        const instance = Template.instance();
        const cardDataId = new Mongo.ObjectID(instance.data.cardData._id.valueOf());
        const limit = 3;
        const allMembersOnCard = CardDataMembers.find({lkp_card_data_fkeyi_ref: cardDataId}).count();
        let remainingMembers = allMembersOnCard - limit;
        return remainingMembers;
    },
```

And in the HTML included:

```
<div class="other-profile" style="background-color:#dedede;">
<span>+{{diffMembers}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in many ways, but I've used **CSS Flexbox**.

I've used two `<div>`s one contains single user circles having class `.each-user` that is expanding (for reference I've taken 6) and another contains the total number of users having class `.total-users`.

It's a bit confusing but if you look into my code below or see this [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/rastogi_saurav/pen/QKeORo) you'll get to know everything.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/* Contains all the circles */
.users-holder {
  display: flex;
}

/* Contains all circles (those without total value written on it) */
.each-user {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 10px;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Circle Styling */
.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.each-user .circle {
  background: #00BCD4;
}

.each-user .circle:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}


/* Circle showing total */
.total-users {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom:
}

.total-users .circle {
  background: #3F51B5;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.total-users .circle .txt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="users-holder">
    <div class="total-users">
      <div class="circle">
        <span class="txt">+12</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="each-user">
      <div class="circle user-circle"></div>
      <div class="circle user-circle"></div>
      <div class="circle user-circle"></div>
      <div class="circle user-circle"></div>
      <div class="circle user-circle"></div>
      <!-- Sixth Circle -->
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will try this out tomorrow and report back to you :) but from what I see now it looks like it might just work :D

Comment: but how do I make this dynamic... the problem is that there wont always be the same amount of users... and how do i even get the users from databse in here

Answer (score 1):

I've used jQuery. See this https://jsfiddle.net/q86x7mjh/26/

HTML:

```
<div class="user-list-container">
    <div class="total-circle hidden"><span></span></div>
    <div class="user-circle"><span>T</span></div>
    <div class="user-circle"><span>C</span></div>
    <div class="user-circle"><span>U</span></div>
    <div class="user-circle"><span>M</span></div>
    <div class="user-circle"><span>R</span></div>
    <div class="user-circle"><span>Z</span></div>
    <div class="user-circle"><span>N</span></div>
    <div class="user-circle"><span>O</span></div>
    <div class="user-circle"><span>M</span></div>
<div>
```

jQuery:

```
var items_to_show = 5;

if($('.user-circle').length > items_to_show){

    var hide = $('.user-circle').length - items_to_show;

    for(var i = 0; i < hide; i++){
        $('.user-circle').eq(i).addClass('hidden');
    }

    $('.total-circle').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.total-circle span').text('+' + hide);

}
```

Comment: Can you put the whole error message in here? Do you have some other jQuery on your site?

Comment: @T K this is the error mesage: "imports/ui/components/cards/cards-view.js:258:5: Unexpected token (258:5)" 
I have plenty of jQuery code in this project...after a quick scroll through more than few K lines of code whritten in diferent files...

Comment: Perhaps if there is a way to write a helper that could be inserted into the html code??

Comment: There is no error in my jQuery, its in yours. In the file `cards-view.js` in `imports/ui/components/cards/`, on line `258`. Did you missed to close a script or html tag?

Comment: @T K From what I see I didnt...  I copied your code and inserted my class names and I get this error

Comment: Could you post your whole code? From the page where my code is.

Comment: It would be better if you post the complete code in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127298/discussion-between-t-k-and-weinde).